# GPA calculator using while loop with switch statement. Java source code

Tags: java, swing

I need to be able to press 'q' in the while loop to get it to exit the loop.  I then need the code to be able to display the credit hours with the grade beside it.  Next I have to display their GPA according to the input of their hours and their grades.  Everytime I press 'q' to exit, the program stops and doesn't display anything.  Please help!

```
package shippingCalc;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Gpa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "";
        String let_grade;
        int credits = 0;
        double letterGrade = 0;
        int course = 1;



        String greeting = "This program will calculate your GPA.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, greeting,"GPA Calculator",1);

            while(!input.toUpperCase().equals("Q"))
            {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the credits for class " + course );
                credits = Integer.parseInt(input);
                course ++;

                    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your grade for your " +credits + " credit hour class");
                    let_grade = input.toUpperCase();
                    char grade = let_grade.charAt(0);

                    letterGrade = 0;
                    switch (grade){
                    case 'A': letterGrade = 4.00;
                        break;
                    case 'B': letterGrade = 3.00;
                        break;
                    case 'C': letterGrade = 2.00;
                        break;
                    case 'D': letterGrade = 1.00;
                        break;
                    case 'F': letterGrade = 0.00;
                        break;

            }

        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, course++ + "\n\n It Works" + letterGrade);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but did you mean `case 'D': letterGrade = 1.00;` and `case 'F': letterGrade = 0.00;`?

Comment: If you enter "q" you should be getting an exception on this line: `credits = Integer.parseInt(input);`

Comment: credits = Integer.parseInt(input);  Yep I am.  How could I change the test expression in the while loop to exit when I need to?

Comment: Actually, this code is working for me, at least as far as the quit option goes: I enter a grade of Q, it shows me the dialog.

Comment: Just an observation; in one iteration of the loop, it's clear when you're getting the number of credits, and it's clear when you're grabbing the letter grade, but it's not clear when you want to test to see whether or not the user wants to exit. As written, it looks like you want to exit if the user inputs `Q` or `q` instead of a letter grade, but that's not made clear elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I think is that credits is an int and right after the second popup

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
"Please enter the credits for class " + course);
```

You assign whatever the user types to the int credits, so if you input a String q or Q its gonna break. Also, keep in mind that the while loop condition is only checked once per iteration, at the start of the iteration, so it won't know about the value of input until that time

There are a couple ways you could fix this. A quick and easy way would be to insert this line of code before assigning the user input to credit

```
 if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
    continue;//will allow input to be checked immediately before assigning to credits
}
```